# When dealing with NgRx, why use Typescript Getter to display properties on templates?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

While studying [this](https://ngrx.github.io/platform/stackblitz.html) NgRx example app, I noticed the use of Typescript Getter to display properties values on the template view. Here's an example:

```
<mat-card-title>{{ title | bcEllipsis:35 }}</mat-card-title>
```

...

```
get title() {
  return this.book.volumeInfo.title;
}
```

Why don't just use a `getTtile()` method or simply call the object property like `book.volumeInfo.title`? Is the `get` approach a better practice nowadays when dealing with either NgRx or Angular in general?

Comment: getter and setter is something popular because it doesn't show you how it works behind. It's more readable when you see `this.title = 'test'` instead of `this.setTitle('test')`. I think this way to write getter/setter comes from C#.

Comment: The getter is especially useful if `this.book` is a service. That way you can expose properties from a private service instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it's just clean code approach. It's definitely much more readable to have `title` in the template than `this.book.volumeInfo.title` or `getTitle()`. In fact `get title()` is also function, just like `getTitle()`.

**Extra:**
But to the honest, it's not the best way to bind value from component to template, as you have to call some function on the template (which is not the best option). You should avoid calling any function or computing any calculations on the template if you really don't have to. Instead you can bind just a property.

**EDIT 1**
When using manual change detection it's good habit to keep your all values which are present on your template in property. For example you can create property called `state` which holds every template-related value. Then, with every change of state's properties' value you can detect changes. In that way you will achieve some sort of clean code and performance.

Comment: I agree. If you don't use "onPush" changeDetection, Angular will be able to render the page faster if you directly access to the property reference.